# How to extract certain JSON data in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, file

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "project details": [ {
            "company name": "Example company name",
            "project name": "Example project name",
            "client": {
                    "name": "Example client",
                    "email": "testing@test.com",
                    "phone": "+44 123456"
                    },
            "Z Contact" : {
                    "name": "Fred Blogs",
                    "email": "fred@z.com",
                    "phone": "+44 123456"
                    }
            } ]
    }
```

Im trying to get speific details, such as the company name, name of the client and the email address of 'Z contact'.

So far i have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Testing2\\src\\testdata.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("project details");
        System.out.println(array);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which will return the entire project details data. I'm a little stuck on how i would get each individual value using Java.

Also, i have this JSON file within the same package as the class reading it from, but when i use

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("\\testdata.json"));
```

Why is this not able to find the file? My solution of using the file's full path works but this is likely to change at run time, so its not suitable.

Comment: The leading backslash refers to the root directory. Try to leave it out. Also, in how far are you stuck?

Comment: It is also not clear from your question which JSON library you are using.

Comment: Sorry, i am using simple JSON library. I'm stuck for the next step of getting the specific such as "company name" and "name" for the "client".

Comment: Omitting the leading backslash leads to java.io.FileNotFoundException: testdata.json (The system cannot find the file specified) error

Comment: Just wondering if your problem is finding the path file? or is it reading each individual element like name, email, phone, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what is available through the simple JSON library's API, given your above code, `array` would contain the following at the end:

```
[ 
    {
      "company name": "Example company name",
      "project name": "Example project name",
      "client": {
              "name": "Example client",
              "email": "testing@test.com",
              "phone": "+44 123456"
      },
      "Z Contact" : {
              "name": "Fred Blogs",
              "email": "fred@z.com",
              "phone": "+44 123456"
      }
    } 
]
```

Now we should be able to do the following:

```
JSONObject project = array.getJsonObject(0);
```

In this case, you would again be able to query the `JSONObject` using `project.get("company name");`

Provided you have POJOs for the given object, the library might also support deserialization to the POJO using something like the following:

```
List<Project> project = array.getValuesAs(Project.class);
```

In this case you would be able to manipulate the list as normal and use normal setters and getters for manipulating the object.

Note that, IMO, wherever possible you should prefer to deserialize your JSON into POJOs if your JSON is not extremely dynamic. In this case, I recommend using the Jackson `ObjectMapper` as it has some very nice features. In addition, take a look at `JSONPath` which might also help you if you require querying a specific part of a JSON payload only.